# Multiple Twitch Channels for one Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website I have a showcase of three channels, I can set the title by having lots of JS files, but I would rather just have one code that will grab the ID's and what not from the HTML

This is what I have for the JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.ttitle').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + tnick + ".json?callback=?", function(data) {
        document.getElementById('twitchtitle').textContent = data.status;
    }

});
```

});

And the HTML

```
<h3 class="ttitle" target="_blank" data-tnick="lethalfrag" id="twitchtitle">Offline</h3>
```

That can most certainly be changed however. All I want it to do is grab the tnick from the HTML and use it in the JavaScript.. not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be updating the text at all, it's just leaving it at "Offline" (Not sure what you mean by Value for Tnick)

Comment: What's the problem? "Doesn't work" is not a good description of whatever's happening. Use your browser's debugger tools, place a breakpoint at the var tnick line, then step through and figure out if you're getting the value you expect. After that, you can ask questions about what's going on.

Comment: Code looks fine except `document.getElementById('twitchtitle').textContent = data.status;`, which would set the title to the last status, as each `.ttitle` is only setting the text. Change that to `document.getElementById('twitchtitle').textContent = document.getElementById('twitchtitle').textContent + ' ' +data.status;`